# Cual es la ventaja de usar std::forward

Tags: c++, template, c++11

Cuando alguien se pone a estudiar el alcance del estándar C++11 suele cruzarse con el término "*perfect forwarding*" (perdón por no poner la traducción pero es casi obvio que la documentación en español no abunda y la traducción literal no me convence).

El caso es que esa terminología se usa muchísimo al hablar de las plantillas.

¿Cuales son las ventajas de `std::forward`?

En el ejemplo que figura a continuación, ¿Qué ventajas (suponiendo que haya alguna) nos proporciona el uso de `std::forward`?

```
template<class T>
void funcion1(T&& parametro)
{
  otraFuncion(std::forward<T>(parametro));
}

template<class T>
void funcion2(T&& parametro)
{
  otraFuncion(parametro);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si dada una plantilla de función `func1(param1, param2)` queremos llamar a una función `func2(param1,param2)` haciendo uso del estándar c++03 podríamos optar por una primera versión tal que:

```
template<class Param1, class Param2>
void func1(Param1 param1, Param2 param2)
{
  func2(param1,param2);
}
```

El problema que presenta esta versión es que si en vez de tipos nativos (`int`, `float`, etc) pasamos un objeto, por ejemplo una cadena, el código va a hacer una copia intermedia del objeto. Pasamos entonces a *mejorar* la plantilla para evitar el problema:

```
template<class Param1, class Param2>
void func1(Param1& param1, Param2& param2)
{
  func2(param1,param2);
}
```

Funciona bastante bien con objetos... peeeero ahora ya no somos capaces de hacer algo tal que:

```
func1(10,5.5);
```

Ya que no podemos obtener una referencia de un `rvalue`. ¿Y si forzamos a que las referencias sean constantes?

```
template<class Param1, class Param2>
void func1(Param1 const& param1, Param2 const& param2)
{
  func2(param1,param2);
}
```

Vale, el problema anterior se ha solucionado pero nos ha aparecido un problema nuevo... el código fallará si `func2` admite referencias no constantes:

```
void func2(int& a, int& b);

int a = 2, b = 0;
func1(a,b); // ERROR: func2 requiere referencias no constantes
```

El problema empieza a crecer, pero parece que aun hay una solución. ¿Qué tal si hacemos uso de `const_cast`? De esta forma eliminamos el modificador `const`:

```
template<class Param1, class Param2>
void func1(Param1 const& param1, Param2 const& param2)
{
  func2(const_cast<Param1&>(param1),const_cast<Param2&>(param2));
}
```

Parece que ahora ya si funciona todo... espera... no, hay algo que no cuadra. ¿Qué sucede si alimentamos la plantilla con elementos constantes?

```
const int a = 2, b = 0;
func1(a,b);
```

En este caso el resultado es indeterminado. En unos casos aparentará funcionar bien y en otros el programa fallará estrepitosamente. ¿El motivo? Que los objetos constantes pueden acabar almacenados en posiciones de memoria de solo lectura y es el propio sistema operativo el que se encarga de controlar que dicha restricción se cumple.

Como ultima solución podemos optar por crear un juego completo de especializaciones para contemplar todas las posibilidades anteriores. De esta forma el compilador elegirá la más adecuada para cada situación y el programa funcionará sin problemas:

```
template<class Param1, class Param2>
void func1(Param1 & param1, Param2 & param2)
{
  func2(param1,param2);
}

template<class Param1, class Param2>
void func1(Param1 const& param1, Param2 & param2)
{
  func2(param1,param2);
}

template<class Param1, class Param2>
void func1(Param1 & param1, Param2 const& param2)
{
  func2(param1,param2);
}

template<class Param1, class Param2>
void func1(Param1 const& param1, Param2 const& param2)
{
  func2(param1,param2);
}
```

El problema evidente de esta última solución es que el número de implementaciones requeridas crece de forma exponencial según el número de argumentos a tratar... y todo a pesar de que la implementación es exactamente la misma.

`std::forward` apareción en el estándar C++11 precisamente para cubrir este nicho. La implementación de `std::forward` según el estándar (ver [§20.2.3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)) es la siguiente:

> *Returns:* static_cast(t).

Y con este fragmento se solucionan todos los errores del tirón y como demostración el siguiente código:

```
template<class T>
void func2(T &)
{ std::cout << "func2(T &)\n"; }

template<class T>
void func2(T const&)
{ std::cout << "func2(T const&)\n"; }

template<class T>
void func2(T &&)
{ std::cout << "func2(T &&)\n"; }

template<class T>
void func(T&& a)
{
    func2(std::forward<T>(a));
}

int f()
{ return 7; }

template<class Func>
void Test(
  const std::string& label,
  Func f)
{
  std::cout << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(14) << std::left << label << " --> ";
  f();
}

int main()
{
    Test("func(T)",        [](){int a; func(a); });
    Test("func(T &)",      [](){int a; int& b = a; func(b); });
    Test("func(T const&)", [](){int a; const int& b = a; func(b); });
    Test("func(T &&)",     [](){ func(1); });
    Test("func(T &&)",     [](){ func(f()); });

    return 0;
}
```

Y su correspondiente resultado:

```
func(T)        --> func2(T &)
func(T &)      --> func2(T &)
func(T const&) --> func2(T const&)
func(T &&)     --> func2(T &&)
func(T &&)     --> func2(T &&)
```

Se pueden hacer pruebas adicionales sobre el ejemplo anterior, comentando una de las tres implementaciones de `func2` y veremos como el programa es capaz de reajustar su comportamiento proporcionando una solución en función de las opciones existentes.

Así, si comentamos `func2(T&)` la salida será:

```
func(T)        --> func2(T &&)
func(T &)      --> func2(T &&)
func(T const&) --> func2(T const&)
func(T &&)     --> func2(T &&)
func(T &&)     --> func2(T &&)
```

Y si, en cambio, comentamos `func2(T const&)` la salida será:

```
func(T)        --> func2(T &)
func(T &)      --> func2(T &)
func(T const&) --> func2(T &)
func(T &&)     --> func2(T &&)
func(T &&)     --> func2(T &&)
```

En este último caso puede llamar la atención la conversión de `T const&` a `T &`. Lo que sucede en este caso es que `T` va a ser constante, luego si `func2(T&)` intenta realizar modificaciones sobre el atributo se producirá un error en tiempo de compilación.

El resultado, como se puede observar, es que `std::forward` proporciona un mecanismo bastante sencillo y elegante para resolver el dilema que surje a la hora de decidir entre `rvalue` y `lvalue`.

¿Y qué sucede si eliminamos `std::forward` en el ejemplo?

```
template<class T>
void func(T&& a)
{
    func2(a);
}
```

Bueno, la salida ahora variará significativamente:

```
func(T)        --> func2(T &)
func(T &)      --> func2(T &)
func(T const&) --> func2(T const&)
func(T &&)     --> func2(T &)
func(T &&)     --> func2(T &)
```

Los efectos principales son que la sobrecarga que hace uso de la *sintaxis move* dejará de ser accesible, por lo que es de esperar una merma en el rendimiento del código sobretodo si la función recibe objetos cuya copia resulte pesada. Esta versión de la función únicamente estará disponible si se elimina alguna de las dos versiones anteriores (`func2(T&)` o `func2(T const&)`) y a estas sobrecargas no podremos renunciar en más de una ocasión por lo que tendremos un problema.

¿Se podría aplicar una solución similar en versiones anteriores a C++11?

Lamentablemente no. Toda esta solución gira en torno a la *sintaxis move* y  la diferenciación entre `rvalue` y `lvalue`. La no está disponible en estándares anteriores y la segunda ha sufrido serias revisiones en el estándar C++11. En C++03 se podría llegar a diferenciar un `rvalue` de un `lvalue` pero el proceso no es ni limpio ni bonito (ver [Conditional Love: FOREACH Redux](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html)).

Así pues, recapitulando:

> ¿Cuales son las ventajas de std::forward?

El motivo de recurrir a `std::forward` es disponer de una herramienta que nos permita, dentro de un template, distinguir un `rvalue` de un `lvalue` ya que esto nos evita tener que recurrir a la tediosa tarea de repetir código en diferentes implementaciones de la plantilla.

> ¿Qué ventajas (suponiendo que haya alguna) nos proporciona el uso de std::forward?

Al poder distinguir entre `lvalue` y `rvalue` el compilador será capaz de llamar a la función más adecuada segun la ocasión.

Answer (score 1):

`std::forward` es una manera de respetar la naturaleza intrínseca del tipo recibido. Hay que tener en cuenta varias cosas:

- Object temporal es sinónimo de objecto anónimo.
- Cuando se utiliza una referencia r-value para un tipo paramétrico, el tipo final no tiene por qué ser una referencia r-value:

Ejemplos:

```
template<class T>
void f(T&& t);

T t;
f(f); // El parámetro tiene tipo T& t;
f(T()); // El parámetro tiene tipo T&& t;
```

Pero independientemente del tipo final del parámetro, una vez que el objecto tiene nombre, deja de ser temporal, y deja de funcionar, en consecuencia, como `r-value`, sino como `l-value`. Por ese motivo, tú puedes asignar a referencias `r-values`, porque una vez dentro de la función, ya no son valores temporales. La referencia r-value solo sirve para "rastrear" el origen de la variable, si antes de la llamada, fue temporal o no.

¿Cómo se le quita el nombre a una referencia r-value? Pues devolviendolo como parámetro:

```
template<class T>
T&& f(T&& t)
{ return t; }
```

Al devolver `t`, el valor devuelto no tiene nombre (desde el punto de vista de la función llamante). Entonces, `std::forward` lo que hace es:

Si el parámetro es una referencia rvalue, es equivalente a la siguiente sintáxis (más o menos):

```
// Le quitamos el nombre para que siga siendo un objecto 
// anónimo/temporal.
template<class T>
T&& forward(T&& t)
{ return t; }
```

Y si es un lvalue:

```
// Se mantiene su condición de lvalue.
template<class T>
T& forward(T& t)
{ return t; }
```

Date cuenta que un lvalor, siempre es un lvalor, aunque se devuelva. Por eso, aunque le quitemos el nombre al devolver la referencia, sigue siendo una referencia a algo que en su origen es un lvalor de verdad, mientras que en el caso de devolver una referencia rvalue, al quitarle el nombre, lo único que queda es que en su origen era un objecto temporal, y por tanto, seguirá siendolo tras el retorno.

Answer (score 0):

`std::forward` es un cast condicional a `rvalue`, que va a actuar sólo en el caso en que `funcion1` se haya invocado con un argumento de tipo `rvalue` (por eso es condicional). Entonces, suponiendo que `parametro` sea efectivamente un `rvalue`, `otraFuncion`, a su vez, va a recibir ese `rvalue` como argumento, ya que de otra manera recibiría un `lvalue`.

Cualquier diferencia (o ventaja, si la hubiera) va a depender de si `otraFuncion` recibe como parámetro un `rvalue`, y qué es lo que hace con él, naturalmente.