# std::forward y rvalue

Tags: c++11

Estoy leyendo sobre el uso de std:forward, mirando un poco los ejemplos que vienen en internet. Y me ha surgido la siguiente duda.

Si defino el templete:

```
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    void outer(T1&& t1, T2&& t2) 
    {
       inner(std::forward<T1>(t1), std::forward<T2>(t2));
    }
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Cuantas funcones inner necestio definir? ¿Cuales serían?. Es decir debo definir inner(&,&), inner(&&,&&), inner(const &, const&) o también debo definir todas las combinaciones de ambas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como primera introducción a [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward), se puede consultar esta otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/54147/463)

La respuesta a tu pregunta es... depende (aunque como norma general diremos que no, no debes crear varias versiones de `inner`).

Normalmente, en aquellos casos en los que se usa `std::forward`, tanto `inner` como `outer` son plantillas. En estos casos suele existir una colección de funciones (`inner1`, `inner2`, ...) y se llamará a una de ellas en función de la especialización de `outer`. Es decir, `outer` no es más que una función que permite abstraerse de la llamada concreta `inner`.

Pues bien, dependiendo de la naturaleza concreta de `inner`, deberás implementar solo aquellas versiones que realmente tengan sentido, dejando que aquellas combinaciones no válidas generen un error en tiempo de compilación.

Por ejemplo, si resulta que el primer parámetro debe ser una referencia no constante (porque ese parámetro puede ser modificado), no tiene sentido que implementes una versión de `inner` con este parámetro como referencia constante, ya que te va a obligar a hacer chapuzas que pueden provocar comportamiento indefinido:

```
void inner(int const& a, int const& b)
{
  static_cast<A&>(a) = b + 5;
}

const int x = 1, y = 2;
outer(x,y); // Comportamiento indefinido, x es constante
```

Ahora bien, si tener varias versiones de `inner` se justifica como medio para cumplir con las especificaciones del proyecto (por ejemplo conseguir unos tiempos de ejecución dados), entonces empieza a tener sentido disponer de un catálogo limitado de `inner` diferentes... pero esta heterogeneidad debe estar lo suficientemente justificada.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha quedado mas claro.