# duda sobre declytype y std::forward

Tags: c++11

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código, relacionado con el tema del *forwarding references*, unido con la deducción de tipos.

```
template<class T>
void wrapper(T&& arg)
{
    foo(forward<decltype(forward<T>(arg).get())>(forward<T>(arg).get()));
}

struct Arg
{
    int i = 1;
    int  get() && { return i; } // call to this overload is rvalue
    int& get() &  { return i; } // call to this overload is lvalue
};
```

**¿Me podés ayudar a entender si entiendo bien el funcionamiento de la línea de la llamada a foo()?**

Supongamos que recibimos un *rvalue* `int`, por las reglas de deducción de las plantillas, `T=int`. Luego en este fragmento:

```
decltype(forward<T>(arg).get())
```

1. Al ser `arg` un `rvalue` se va llamar al primer función `get()` de `Arg`, que nos devuelve `i_type=int`.
2. `forward<int>`, va devolver `int&&` (referencia *rvalue*).
3. `decltype(expr)` va devolver `int&&`.

Quedando entonces:

```
 foo(forward<int&&>(forward<int>(arg).get());

 foo(int&& i);
```

¿Sería correcto el razonamiento?.

Comment: Sería recomendable que pusieses un ejemplo de qué es lo que quieres conseguir... hay varias formas de *adivinar* el tipo y creo que sería más conveniente darte una respuesta en el sentido que tu esperas

Comment: ok, Reformulo la pregunta poniendo el ejemplo en cuestión. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

> Supongamos que recibimos un rvalue int, por las reglas de deducción de las plantillas, T=int. Luego en este fragmento:
>
> ```
> decltype(forward(arg).get())
> ```
>
> 1. Al ser arg un *rvalue* se va llamar al primer función `get()` de `arg`, que nos devuelve `i_type=int`.
> 2. `forward`, va devolver `int&&` (referencia rvalue).
> 3. `decltype(expr)` va devolver `int&&`.

No es un planteamiento correcto.

`decltype` **no ejecuta** nada... únicamente **evalúa** (si ejecutase podría modificar valores y eso nunca va a suceder). Así pues, `decltype` va a evaluar la expresión que se le está pasando, `forward(arg).get()` y *copiará* el tipo final de la expresión.

Como `decltype` no va a ejecutar código, carece de sentido utilizar `forward`, ya que en este caso nos va a dar igual trabajar con un *R-value* o con un *L-value* (no se va a crear ninguna copia ni a realizar ningún movimiento). Así pues `forward(arg)` es equivalente a `arg`. Ahora la llamada queda más sencilla: `decltype(arg.get())`. ¿Y cual es el tipo de retorno de la llamada `arg.get()`? exacto, `int`, luego `decltype(forward(arg).get())` se convierte en `int`.

No olvidemos que `decltype` se procesa en **tiempo de compilación** luego al binario le llega el resultado de dicho procesamiento. Si examinas el ensamblado verás que no hay referencia alguna a `decltype`... `decltype` se usa para dejar que sea el compilador el que determine cual debe ser el tipo... y esta elección se hace en tiempo de compilación.

### Bonus

`std::forward` es una utilidad que permite que el compilador determine si un parámetro se debe usar como *R-value* o como *L-value*. Puedes encontrar más información al respecto en esta otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/54147/463).

Como ves, `std::forward` solo tiene sentido cuando tratas con argumentos en funciones de tipo plantilla porque a dichas funciones se les puede pasar un *R-value* o un *L-value* y, a priori, tu no tienes mecanismos para determinar qué hacer en cada caso.

Esto viene a que el `std::forward` que rodea a `get` no tiene ningún sentido... lo que tratas de decidir es si tienes que usar `arg` como *R-value* o como *L-value*... pero una vez decidido esto la llamada a `get` no va a ser tan traumática porque la propia función ya tiene un tipo de retorno que va a ser inamovible.

En principio podrías alegar que el retorno de `get` es variable porque tienes dos versiones de dicha función... y es cierto... pero lo que determina a qué `get` llamas no depende del `std::forward` que rodea al `get` sino del `std::forward` que rodea a `arg`:

```
Arg a;
a.get() = 10;            // Ok, int& get()
std::move(a).get() = 10; // Error, int get() &&
```

Así pues la plantilla se podría simplificar enormemente:

```
template<class T>
void wrapper(T&& arg)
{
    foo(std::forward<T>(arg).get());
}
```